# What is the point of converting conditional probability to factor for Variable Elimination?

Tags: bayesian-networks, random-variable, conditional-probability

[image]

I have this slide from my AI class on using a Bayes network to compute a conditional probability. I don't really understand the point of converting the conditional probabilities to factors (besides the fact that it looks weird to marginalize or multiply variables in a CP). It seems kind of arbitrary. Is there some benefit I'm not noticing?

Comment: the benefit is that you are utilizing the distributions factorization to simplify marginalization (which on the joint is extremely expensive!)